# testthat::expect_equal, tolerance isn't working for me

Tags: r, testthat

Here is the test environment:

```
packageVersion("testthat")
# [1] ‘3.1.6`

testthat_tolerance()
# [1] 1.490116e-08
```

But when I run it, it fails on differences well below that tolerance:

```
Gamma <- 0.00020237234
expect_equal(Gamma, 0.0002023723)
```

```
Error: Gamma (actual) not equal to 0.0002023723 (expected).

actual:   0.00020237234
expected: 0.00020237230
```

Setting the tolerance myself doesn't fix the problem:

```
expect_equal(Gamma, 0.0002023723, tolerance = 1e-8)
```

```
Error: Gamma (actual) not equal to 0.0002023723 (expected).

  actual : 0.00020237234
expected : 0.00020237230`
```

But if I relax the tolerance it passes the test:

```
expect_equal(Gamma, 0.0002023723, tolerance = 1e-6)
```

For my purposes, `1e-6` is good enough, but I feel like either there's a bug or I'm missing something.

I ran it from a file and from the console with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

From man page for [expect_equal](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/blob/main/man/equality-expectations.Rd)

> tolerance: passed on to waldo::compare(). If non-NULL, will ignore small floating point differences. It uses same algorithm as all.equal() so the tolerance is usually relative (i.e.mean(abs(x - y) / mean(abs(y)) < tolerance), except when the differences are very small, when it becomes absolute (i.e. mean(abs(x - y) < tolerance).

So in your case tolerance may be relative.

Comment: Yes, that's it, it is responding to the relative cutoff.  Thank you.